# How to use a positive lookahead to replace all, but one http(s):// in a string?

Tags: php, regex

How to use a positive lookahead to replace all, but one http(s):// in a string?

I have user input that some times includes multiple http:// or https://'s in the string e.g. `http://http://wwww.site.com/` and I need to remove all instances, BUT one. I've read about using a positive lookahead in a regex pattern, but cannot seem to make it work.

I've tried the following:

```
preg_replace( 'https?://(?=.*https?://)', '', $url );
```

Comment: Your replacement pattern is missing the regex delimiters that `preg_` requires (any non-alpha-numeric character before and after the regex)

Comment: Code added and thanks Jan for pointing that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$url = preg_replace("#(https?://)+#", "$1", $url);
```

Comment: This one is much better ;)

Comment: I think it might be more usefull to keep the last occurence though... In my opinion, such a behavior happens when people type http:// and paste chrome's URL witch adds the http(s):// prefix automatically. The good one would be the last one.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the last one.

Answer (score 2):

This could work :

```
<?php

$text = 'http://https://http://http://https://abc.com';
$text = preg_replace('#(https?://)+https?://#iU', '', $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Losing the `s` could be fixed by using a group like `(s?)` and then using `\1` in the replacement text.

Comment: Think i made a little mistake : if the last one is http (without s), it removes all of the http(s):// occurences... Idea anyone ?

Comment: Second mistake, no need to escape slashes ! ring0 made it much cleaner.